# Open a local folder in a VSCode Remote-SSH session

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Code 1.50.1 on Windows 10.

I'd like to develop on a remote virtual machine running in Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2). This works fine, but I can't open a local directory on the remote VM.

I would specifically like to be able to mount a local folder on my development system as my working directory. The functionality I'm seeking is similar to how the `Remote-Containers` extension works, where you can mount a directory into a container.

**Question**: Is it possible to mount a local folder into a Remote-SSH session in VSCode? If so, how?